# Django template importing when creating a package

Tags: python, django

I'm create a new package, something very simple. I'm confused tho, how should I be doing templates?

You see I never know what project this application gets installed on i.e. `pip install django-something`, but I would like the 'something app' to inherent the template of the project its used on.

Is this my job, how do other do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to "namespace" your own app's templates.
Instead of storing your app's templates in `yourapp/templates/foo.html`, add another directory inside your templates directory: `yourapp/templates/yourapp/foo.html`.

This means you can distinguish between your *app's* `base.html` and the *project's* `base.html`.

In your app's templates (for example, 'foo.html'), you inherit your app's base template:

```
{% extends "yourapp/base.html" %}`.
```

You can then inherit from the project's base.html (if it exists), by starting it with:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

Comment: If you are wondering which "blocks" to include in your templates, for maximum reusability, this is a good post: http://ericholscher.com/blog/2008/nov/20/gentlemans-agreement-django-templates/

Answer (score 1):

Put the template in a location where the loaders configured in the project will find before they start looking in the app directories.

E.G.

If you have:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = ('django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader')

TEMPLATE_DIRS = 'myproject/templates'
```

and the app looks for `foo/bar.html`, then you just need to create `myproject/templates/foo/bar.html` in order to override the built-in template.